# Execute PIPE on string not found in bash output

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, xargs

My desired result flow is as below:but am not sure how to use for-loop here. Please observe in my expression where am trying to validate string1 does not exist in output of every node.

- get output of command that match DISABLED string, which gives a list of matched nodes.
  Ex:

  ```
  kubectl get nodes | grep -i DISABLED
  ```

  Example: output is

  ```
  node1-DISABLED node2-DISABLED node3-DISABLED
  ```
- for each of the nodes that I get above, I am doing describe on them like
  Ex:

  ```
  kubectl describe nodes $1
  ```
- then on output of describe, I want to see what all nodes DON'T have "string1" string in their describe output command and then if not found, echo/print that node

So my complete expression looks like this

```
kubectl get nodes | grep -i DISABLED | 
awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' | 
xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'kubectl describe node "$1"' | 
for grep -e "string1" == 0; do 
xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'echo "$1"' --; done
```

Example output from partial commands:

```
bash$ kubectl get nodes | grep -i DISABLED
10.4.5.15-59fa4f88   Ready,SchedulingDisabled   node      20d       v1.10.9   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS   4.15.0-15-generic   docker://18.3.1

10.4.5.16-59fa4f88   Ready,SchedulingDisabled   node      20d       v1.10.9   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS   4.15.0-15-generic   docker://18.3.1


bash$ kubectl get nodes | grep -i DISABLED | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'
10.4.5.15-59fa4f88
10.4.5.16-59fa4f88
```

Expected output is:

```
10.4.5.15-59fa4f88
```

Because node 10.4.5.15-59fa4f88 does not have string1 in its describe output and 10.4.5.16 is not echoed because its description has string1 in its describe output.

Basically, I am trying to build an expression that will describe every node and check for string1 in it, if not there it will echo that node out to terminal.

Output of

```
kubectl describe node $1

Name:               10.4.5.15-59fa4f88
Roles:              node
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=gdd5_8dd.dd2xlarge
                beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=sdjcd2d01-sw-05
                kops.k8s.io/instancegroup=nodes-test
                kubernetes.io/hostname=10.4.5.15-59fa4f88
                kubernetes.io/role=node
                node-role.kubernetes.io/node=
Annotations:        d.volume.kubernetes.io/nodeid={"d-d":"10.4.5.15-59fa4f88"}
                node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl=0
                volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach=true
CreationTimestamp:  Wed, 28 Nov 2018 07:37:39 -0800
Taints:             <none>
```

Comment: observe the output of `echo 1 | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'echo \$0=$0 \$1=$1'` and 
`echo 1 | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'echo \$0=$0 \$1=$1' --` . Btw, you can insert a newline into your script after `|`, thus make your script more readable. Can you post example output of `kubectl get nodes`? Can you post example expected output and the output you are getting? Be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: done. also why do i have to observe the output you mentioned above? can you clarify?

Comment: You want `sh -c 'echo $0'` not `... $1'` The first arg after `sh -c '' this_arg` becomes `$0`.

Comment: @AhmFM: The program which you have posted is syntactically incorrect and can not have produced the output you wrote here. The reason is that the line `for grep -e "string1" == 0; do` is syntactically incorrect: _bash: syntax error near unexpected token `-e'_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code can be substantially simplified.  Try this:

```
kubectl get nodes |
# Awk can do everything grep can do, and then some
awk 'toupper($0) ~ /DISABLED/ { print $1 }' |
# loop over results
while read -r node; do
    kubectl describe node "$node" |
    grep -q "string1" || echo "$node"
done
```

If the output from `kubectl describe node` contains the node name somewhere (say, the first field?) then the `while` loop could probably be replaced with something like

```
# xargs already knows how to run a command
xargs -n 1 kubectl describe node |
# Simply filter out anything with string1
awk '! /string1/ { print $1 }'
```

If you want to weed out duplicates, tack on `| sort -u` or in the latter case implement simple duplicate removal within the Awk script (hint: keep an associative arrays of values you have seen, and only print when something isn't already in the array).

Updated in response to edit: Here's an Awk attempt which extracts and prints the Name: field if none of the output contains `start1`.

```
kubectl get nodes |
awk 'toupper($0) ~ /DISABLED/ { print $1 }' |
xargs -n 1 kubectl describe node |
awk '/^Name: / { if (NR>1 && name) print name
        name=$2 }
    /string1/ { name="" }
    END { if (name) print name }'
```

The Awk script will assign `name` when it sees the beginning of a new output. If a previous `name` was set then first we print that (the previous record). The second regex unsets `name` if it sees `string1` so that it won't be printed when we reach the next record.  Finally, in `END` we catch the last name if it was set.

Comment: I added output of `kubectl describe node $1` and yes it has node name as first field

Comment: awesome ! your while solution works. but not sure about xargs you mentioned. its not working

Comment: You put that after the pipe from `awk 'toupper($0) ...' |`?

Comment: Updated with a version which parses the `xargs kubectl describe` output.

Comment: i have a clarifications in your while solution though to understand: what does `grep -q "maglev" ||` do? two pipes does what? and what is 'toupper($0)

Comment: Those are not pipes, that's "or" (though the symbol is identical to the pipe, only twice).  If grep succeeds then we are done; if it fails, do the `echo`.  There is also `&&` for "and".

Comment: `toupper` converts its argument to upper case and `$0` is the current input line in Awk.

Comment: i have a follow up question to this shall i open new question or just below is fine?
basically, i want to do combination grep that is check string1 exists and string2 does not exists and if this is true echo $node

basically, add not exist expression with string2

Comment: please help extend this as its working:
`| awk 'toupper($0) ~ /DISABLED/ { print $1 }' | while read -r node; do kubectl describe node "$node" | grep -q "string1" || echo "$node"; done

Comment: Sounds like you should go ahead and ask a new question. Do link back here for context and feel free to ping me when you have it down. Your problem statement sounds like you should try to use Awk all the way.